# SQL - Delete Cascade is used with?

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and I'm stuck on one of the review questions and can't find an answer in the text book. When you 'delete cascade'

What is it 'used' with?

- a. it is used together with a primary key constraint
- b. it is used together with a unique constraint
- c. it is used together with a referential constraint
- d. it is used together with a type constraint

I want to say primary key because it is going to identify the correct tuple when it cascades? Am I right/wrong, I just don't know which one is right.

Thanks.

Comment: `DELETE CASCADE` is used with `Foreign Key` columns, so `C` is the correct one here.

Comment: Think through it this way:  For something to cascade, that implies it affects more than one element/node/item/whatever. `ON DELETE CASCADE` implies that a deletion causes a cascading action onto another element/node/item/whatever. So the correct answer is `C`, referential constraints (foreign keys). A row is deleted, and related rows in other tables (or the same table) via FK constraints are also deleted since the common element between them no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

it is used together with a referential constraint.

more about [Referential CONSTRAINT](http://www.sapdb.org/7.4/htmhelp/6d/117c5fd14811d2a97400a0c9449261/content.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It deletes all records that have FKs to that record.

[See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b29324/1)

---

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id  serial, 
   num int, 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO foo(num) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE TABLE bar ( 
   foo_id bigint unsigned,
   FOREIGN KEY (foo_id) REFERENCES foo (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO bar(foo_id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

DELETE FROM bar WHERE foo_id = 3;  -- notice 3 is only removed from bar
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id = 2;      -- notice 2 is removed from both foo and bar
```

When the record from `foo` is deleted, any constraints that reference a key of that record and have `delete cascade` specified, will also automatically be deleted.  Without that specification, when the record in `foo` is deleted, the database will send an error message if any foreign dependencies still exist at the end of the transaction.

Comment: It was downvoted because your original answer implied that the OP was correct in assuming DELETE CASCADE is used with PKs. Cascade deletion is used with FK's, which are synonyms for referential constraints. You're still vaguely implying that the OP's guess was correct.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I see, despite specifying that it only happens for `FKs` -- I'll remove the `Right` as it's ambiguous and misleading; thx